# How to run a batch file when user run RDP icon via task scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I am using windows 10 and looking for a way to clear RDP history ( IP address, Username And Password ). As you know RDP history keeps listed and cannot be deleted Only if you go through registry editor or removing default RDP icon from Documents folder.

I have this batch file :

```
echo off
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default" /va /f
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers"
cd %userprofile%\documents\
attrib Default.rdp -s -h
del Default.rdp
```

That runs exactly what I needed- it removes all credentials and IP address. The question is when I'm trying to use windows task scheduler to run this batch file when a trigger condition runs. (The condition I'm looking for is when user clicks or run RDP connection).

Running the task manually works, but it is not working when I click on RDP connection- How can this be solved?
I don't mind if it works other way as when user exists / disconnects from RDP session. All I care about not to show any credentials when user wants to create a new session.

Thank You

**Edit:**

Screenshots of task scheduler properties :
[image]

[image]

[image]

The above created under administrator account.

Comment: Have you created the task with the highest credentials (administrator)?

Comment: Yes I did, Also forgot to mention my trigger condition which is - On an Event - > Log:  Application - > Source :RemoteApp and Desktop Connection and Event ID:  blank...Is this correct ?

Comment: It would be better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1617561/edit) your question and add screenshots of the relevant screens of the task.

Comment: @harrymc I've added screenshots based on your request.

Comment: Do I understand right: You wish to intercept the running of RDP and clear the history before the program starts?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, correct.

Comment: @harrymc or could be the opposite way, as when user exit / disconnect from the RDP session, it will clear the history right after.

Comment: The first method will involve replacing the icon with a script. The second will require a watch program to detect the ending of RDP. Do you have a preference?

Comment: @harrymc I prefer the first method, I do appreciate your kind help my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDP command is called `mstsc` and should already be in the PATH
since it resides in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Since you mentioned an icon that launches RDP, you could replace it by an icon
that calls a script that will clear the history and launch `mstsc`.

For example:

```
echo off
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default" /va /f
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers"
cd %userprofile%\documents\
attrib Default.rdp -s -h
del Default.rdp
"C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe"
```

If you would prefer to instead clear the history after `mstsc` did its work,
you could use for that the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
You would use a AutoHotkey script for checking every few seconds for `mstsc`
running, starting a timer, then clearing the history when it terminates.

Comment: Thank you very much, that extra line worked as needed. However the cmd wont close after RDP launch so I added additional start code `START "" "C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe" `, now cmd closes after mstsc.exe run. I'll look also for the AutoHotkey to learn more about it. Thanks my friend.